# model data not displaying in view using backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

i am trying to learn backbone.js
trying to get data from php then display it by model, view and route of backbone.js

but its not displaying my data, it displaying [object Object]

you can see output here::
http://php-backbone.gopagoda.com/

and the source code::
https://github.com/foysal-mamun/php-backbone

i have console.log my this.model, you can see my data in::
this.model.attributes.message

please help me how can i fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: You can access model attributes using model.get('key'). I hope that's what you mean to model data.

Comment: @user10 answer is right, but about `$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.attributes));` I don't agree  with @user. `this.model.toJSON()` is more commonly used then `this.model.attributes`

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich, yes your right.
does "success" function use in fetch is good?
or is there any better option to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: @FoysalMamun, using `success` inside `fetch` is good. I try to explain my opinion with your code
`messageModel.fetch();
$('#msg').html(messageView.render().el);`
in this case first row javascript sent query to server, but it don't wait reponse and continues to work in second row, in second row model will be empty, because model didn't get response from sever

Comment: About other ways, I know only one way:it is using `.on`. You have to  bind to model's change event, [to more info](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) with them you can catch when model changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change like below in your router.

```
this.messageModel.fetch({success: function () {
    $('#msg').html(this.messageView.render().el);
}}
```

and change like below in your render function.

```
$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
```

Comment: Thanks, its working.
But i used "this.model.toJSON()" in render function.

So i think, the problem of my previous code is::
render function is calling before fetching model complete.
am i right?